# keycloak REST API: Localize error messages?

Tags: rest, internationalization, keycloak, locale

I wonder how to localize the error messages that are returned from the Keycloak REST API. For example, I get

```json
{"errorMessage":"User exists with same username"}
```

- Is there a Keycloak setting to localize them (for example to the current user's locale setting)?
- A hard-coded client-side mapping "User exists with same username" -> "Der Benutzername existiert bereits." does not seem reasonable(?)

cf.

- https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/07129329c3716f2f31a0515301cec7b770e90e34/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UsersResource.java#L141
- https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/07129329c3716f2f31a0515301cec7b770e90e34/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/ErrorResponse.java#L31

Localization does not seem to be implemented on the Keycloak side(?)

Comment: Could you find a solution? I am struggling with the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not.